# View variable is not accessible in template

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

in my PagesController::display() i have this code :

```
class PagesController extends AppController {

    public function display(...$path) {
        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }
        if (in_array('..', $path, true) || in_array('.', $path, true)) {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }
        $page = $subpage = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage'));

        try {
            $this->render(implode('/', $path));
        } catch (MissingTemplateException $exception) {
            if (Configure::read('debug')) {
                throw $exception;
            }
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
        $test = "abc";
        $this->set(compact('test'));
    }
}
```

That's almost the same as [the standard pages controller](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/92dc4db41395f55c08ae94f20074f0fd26147ddb/src/Controller/PagesController.php#L41), I added the last two lines.

My home.ctp template contains:

```
<?php
var_dump($test);
...
```

When I access the site, this outputs:

```
C:\wamp64\www\site\src\Template\Pages\home.ctp:322:null
```

Which is confusing because debug kit shows that this variable was set:

[image: debug kit variables panel]

Why is the test variable not available in the home.ctp template?

Comment: Please share the code as text (using the `{}` icon to format it) instead of pictures.

Comment: I'd guess you're out of scope, but not really clear with what you posted. Too minimal.

Comment: @Jeto  Thank's for you'r help, i have edit my post

Comment: @user3783243 Thank's you too for help, i have edit my post

Comment: `$test` only exists in the scope of `display()`

Comment: @user3783243 so why can i see $test in my debug kit ?

Comment: Debug kit has the wrong scope? No idea, don't know what you are debugging with either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Render is being called before set

```
   try {
        $this->render(implode('/', $path)); <----
    } catch (MissingTemplateException $exception) {
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            throw $exception;
        }
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    $test = "abc";
    $this->set(compact('test')); <-----
}
```

The call to set is simply too late - it is after the template has already been used.

To have any effect the set call must be before calling render i.e.:

```
$test = 'abc';
$this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'test')); <---

try {
    $this->render(implode('/', $path)); <---
...
```

## Why does the variable show up in DebugKit?

DebugKit interrogates the controller instance to obtain the view variables used - But this runs [right at the end of the request](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/blob/556d7b97fe6efd796616af99c0c94918ccb0087c/src/Panel/VariablesPanel.php#L138). This is the reason it is found by debug kit even though it was not available in the template.